# How to link nested json relationship values objects with lodash?

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

i'm trying to assign/merge (really don't know which lodash function) to nested json objects.

I have the following json structure:

```
{
"sports": [{
        "id": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d",
        "name": "Soccer",
        "slug": "soccer"
    }],
"competitions": [{
        "id": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe",
        "name": "English Premier League",
        "sportId": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d"
    }],
"contests": [{
        "id": "09cee598-7736-4941-b5f5-b26c9da113fc",
        "name": "Super Domingo Ingles",
        "status": "live",
        "competitionId": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe"
    }]
}
```

I want to get one `contest` object with their relationship linked nested. The expected object is something like this:

```
{
        "id": "09cee598-7736-4941-b5f5-b26c9da113fc",
        "name": "Super Domingo Ingles",
        "status": "live",
        "competition": {
           "id": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe",
           "name": "English Premier League",
           "sport": {
             "id": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d",
              "name": "Soccer",
              "slug": "soccer"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

How can I get this kinda of relationship done using lodash ? It can be using pure javascript as well.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special assignment operator, or lodash. You just use the `=`.

```js
ogObject = {
"sports": [{
        "id": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d",
        "name": "Soccer",
        "slug": "soccer"
    }],
"competitions": [{
        "id": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe",
        "name": "English Premier League",
        "sportId": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d"
    }],
"contests": [{
        "id": "09cee598-7736-4941-b5f5-b26c9da113fc",
        "name": "Super Domingo Ingles",
        "status": "live",
        "competitionId": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe"
    }]
};
newObject = ogObject.contests[0];
for(var i = 0; i<ogObject.competitions.length;i++){
    if(ogObject.competitions[i].id == newObject.competitionId){
        newObject.competition = ogObject.competitions[i];
        for(var j = 0; j<ogObject.sports.length;j++){
            if(ogObject.sports[j].id == newObject.competition.sportId){
                newObject.competition.sport = ogObject.sports[j];
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
console.log(newObject)
```

This might be a builtin from lodash but I doubt it. It would require predefined knowledge of your schema vis-a-vis the relationship between sportId and sports, competitionId and competitions etc...

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in lodash function that can be used to flatten relational JSON structures. But something like this should work for you:

```js
    const sourceJSON = {
    "sports": [{
            "id": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d",
            "name": "Soccer",
            "slug": "soccer"
        }],
    "competitions": [{
            "id": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe",
            "name": "English Premier League",
            "sportId": "c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d"
        }],
    "contests": [{
            "id": "09cee598-7736-4941-b5f5-b26c9da113fc",
            "name": "Super Domingo Ingles",
            "status": "live",
            "competitionId": "4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe"
        }]
    }

    function findSport(source, sportId) {
     let sport = _.find(source['sports'], {id: sportId});
     if(!sport) {
      return {};
     }
    
     return {
      id: sport.id,
      name: sport.name,
      slug: sport.slug,
     } 
    }
    
    function findCompetition(source, competitionId) {
     let competition = _.find(source['competitions'], {id: competitionId});
     if(!competition) {
      return {};
     }
    
     return {
      id: competition.id,
      name: competition.name,
      sport: findSport(source, competition.sportId),
     }
    }
    
    function flattenContests(source) {
     return _.map(source['contests'], (contest) => {
      return {
       id: contest.id,
       name: contest.name,
       status: contest.status,
       competition: findCompetition(source, contest.competitionId),
      }
     }); 
    }
    
    console.log(flattenContests(sourceJSON));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that considering your original JSON, the flattened object should likely be an array of `contests` (since `contests` itself is an array) instead of a single contest object that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to show us what you have tried so that we can advise you about the problems that you are facing, otherwise you are just asking for a code writing service ($).

However, in ES2016 you could do this.

```js
'use strict';

const obj = {
  sports: [{
    id: 'c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d',
    name: 'Soccer',
    slug: 'soccer',
  }],
  competitions: [{
    id: '4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe',
    name: 'English Premier League',
    sportId: 'c60d0c48-151e-4fa2-bdf8-48cdfa77ad1d',
  }],
  contests: [{
    id: '09cee598-7736-4941-b5f5-b26c9da113fc',
    name: 'Super Domingo Ingles',
    status: 'live',
    competitionId: '4c19ca7c-4d17-46ce-bb4e-e25a4ebe5dbe',
  }],
};

const transformed = obj.contests.map((contest) => {
  const competition = obj.competitions.find(item => item.id === contest.competitionId);
  const sport = obj.sports.find(item => item.id === competition.sportId);
  const sportLevel = { ...sport };
  const competitionLevel = { ...competition, sport: sportLevel };
  delete competitionLevel.sportId;
  const contestLevel = { ...contest, competition: competitionLevel };
  delete contestLevel.competitionId;
  return contestLevel;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(transformed, null, 2));
```